# How to build only usb-storage.ko?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

How can I build usb-storage.ko module for a running kernel distro (ubuntu)

thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You need the kernel source and kernel configuration (just as for compiling the complete kernel).

To build only a single file, tell `make` about it:

```
make drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko
```

Comment: thank you @CL. 
While doing as you suggested, it gives me a version mismatch.
uname -r: `2.6.35-22-generic`
Can you please suggest any change in Makefile for version matching compilation !!!

Comment: This means you have not the correct version of the source, or have not the correct configuration.

Comment: what does `generic` specifies in kernel version ?
I tried with kernel version - `2.6.35` and gave mismatch.
Please give clue to work on configuration if needed !!!